# how to Save MQTT messages in Database using PhpMyadmin

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, mqtt

just I want to know how to save MQTT messages In Database I have used PhpMyAdmin to create a database but I don't know how to let the MQTT Broker send the Messages to PhpMyAdmin

Comment: HAve you tried MQTT documentation at http://mqtt.org/documentation? Let's try something and share your code...

Comment: Show us what you've tried and we'll help you fix it